# How do I insert images on Java Creator

Tags: java

I seek some help with Java Creator, I have some trouble using images on the program.

I tried using both, URL mode and desktop one.

[This is how it looks on my program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf7Qe.png)
[This is the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M84wd.png)

// here is where im trying to do the image

```
    if(menu==1)
    {
       final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://prntscr.com/fq9ary"));  
    Circulo obj1 = new Circulo();
    obj1.asignar1(radio);

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\t\t CIRCULO \nLa longitud del Circulo es: "+obj1.calcularLong()+"\n El area del Circulo es: "+obj1.calcularArea(), icon);

    }  } }
```

//

Comment: Add your code here with your question.

Comment: I can't send the screenshot because I'm a new user, instead stackoverflow let me put those hyperlinks on my post, the thing im trying to do its to display an image after doing some process, for example in my program I must show the image of a circle after calculating its area and its length.

Comment: You can edit your code in your question as text. Screenshot of your code isn't helpful in any way. We have to reproduce the same issue to identify the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(menu==1)
{
   URL url = new URL("http://prntscr.com/fq9ary");
   BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(url);
   final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);  
   Circulo obj1 = new Circulo();
   obj1.asignar1(radio);
   input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"\t\t CIRCULO \nLa longitud del Circulo es: "+obj1.calcularLong()+"\n El area del Circulo es: "+obj1.calcularArea(), icon);
}
```